# Photoshop suddenly shows artifacts on my file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, smartobject, creative-cloud, visual-artifacts

I am running Photoshop CC on Mac OSX 10.9.1.

Today I opened one of my PSD files this morning and all of a sudden, these artifacts appear in some layers that have some effects on smart objects (but not limited too).

Is this something someone experience? can this be fixed for this file? I tried fixing it myself but new ones appeared.

[image: Artifacts suddenly appear on image1]
[image: Artifacts suddenly appear on image2]

Comment: Looks like corruption due to bad ram, a bad file, bad video, or a bad hard drive. Is it just one file or several? If you reopen the file, are the issues in a different location? This is really more of a hardware issue than a design issue.

Comment: I just google photoshop+stackexchange and ended up here. Thanks for the information - I'll try to run some scans

Comment: first point of action is to disable opengl/gpu accelerated drawing